# 500 internal server error while uploading images django

Tags: python, ajax, django, nginx, django-1.9

I have a form which is divided into two parts. I mean form has rental information fields and multiple image upload.I have used reactjs in frontend and django in backend.Rentals information are successfully saved to database but images are not.It throws 500 internal server error.I have my app deployed on digital ocean(nginx, gunicorn are used).Link to my app is commonrentspace.me

Here is my code

**AddRent.js(Upload image code is focused more for shortening code line)**

```
 let image = [];
 class RenderPhotos extends React.Component {
    constructor(props, context) {
        super(props, context);
        this.state = {
            files: []
        };
    }

    onDrop(files) {
      console.log('Received files: ', files);
      this.setState({
          files: files
      });

           function getCookie(name) {
            var cookieValue = null;
            if (document.cookie && document.cookie != '') {
                var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
                for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
                    var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
                    // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
                    if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) == (name + '=')) {
                        cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            return cookieValue;
        }
        var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');
        function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
            return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
        }
        $.ajaxSetup({
                beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
                    if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
                        xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
                    }
                }
            });
            image = new FormData(files);
            $.each(files,function(i,file){
              image.append('image',file);
            });

    }

    showFiles() {
        const { files } = this.state;
        console.log('files',files);

        if (!files.length) {
            return null;
        }

        return (
            <div>
                <h3>Dropped files: </h3>
                <ul className="gallery">
                    {
                        _.map(files,(file, idx) => {
                            return (
                              <div className="col-md-3">
                                  <li key={idx}>
                                      <img src={file.preview} className="img-fluid" width={200}/>
                                      <div className="imageName">{file.name}</div>
                                  </li>
                                </div>
                            )
                        })
                    }
                </ul>
            </div>
        );
    }

    render() {
      return (
           <div>
                <h3 className="formHeadingh3">Photos can bring your space to life</h3>
                <p>Add photos of spaces to give more insight of your space </p>
                <hr/>
                <div className="col-md-12">
                <form method="POST" encType="multipart/form-data">
                <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="{{ csrf_token }}"/>
                  <Dropzone onDrop={this.onDrop.bind(this)}
                          style={style}
                          activeStyle={activeStyle}
                          accept="image/*">
                    Try dropping some files here, or click to select files to upload.
                </Dropzone>
              </form>
                {this.showFiles()}
              </div>
              <div className="row continueBtn text-right">
                    <button className="btn how-it-works pull-left" onClick={this.props.previousStep.bind(this)}><i className="fa fa-hand-o-left"></i></button>
                    <button className="btn how-it-works pull-right" onClick={this.nextStep.bind(this)}>Submit</button>
               </div>
            </div>

      );
    }

       nextStep(step){
                  var sendData={'ownerName':this.props.fieldValues.ownerName,
                        'email':this.props.fieldValues.email,
                        'phoneNumber':this.props.fieldValues.phoneNumber,
                        'listingName':this.props.fieldValues.listingName,
                        'summary':this.props.fieldValues.summary,
                        'property':this.props.fieldValues.property,
                        'room':this.props.fieldValues.room,
                        'price':this.props.fieldValues.price,
                        'city':this.props.fieldValues.city,
                        'place':this.props.fieldValues.place,
                        'water':this.props.fieldValues.water,
                        'amenities':this.props.fieldValues.amenities.join(', ')
                      }
                  $.ajax({
                  url:"/add/space/",
                  data:sendData,
                  type:'POST',
                  success: function(data, textStatus, xhr ) {
                    var pk = xhr.getResponseHeader('pk-user');
                    console.log('pk is',pk);
                    $.ajax({
                     url:"/upload/image/"+pk+"/",
                     data:image,
                     contentType:false,
                     processData:false,
                     type:'POST',
                     mimeType: "multipart/form-data",
                     success: function(data) {
                       console.log('success');
                     }
                    });
                   window.location.href="http://commonrentpspace.me/"; // if i use this to redirect, the images does not get upload
                  }
                 });
       }


}
```

**Views.py**

```
class AddView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'rentals/add.html'

class AddSpaceView(View):
    def post(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
        print ('add space view',request)
        if request.POST:
            response = HttpResponse('')
            print('owner name is',request.POST.get('ownerName'))
            print('amenities',request.POST.get('amenities'))
            rental = Rental()
            rental.ownerName = request.POST.get('ownerName')
            rental.email = request.POST.get('email')
            rental.phoneNumber = request.POST.get('phoneNumber')
            rental.listingName = request.POST.get('listingName')
            rental.summary = request.POST.get('summary')
            rental.property = request.POST.get('property')
            rental.room = request.POST.get('room')
            rental.price = request.POST.get('price')
            rental.city = request.POST.get('city')
            rental.place = request.POST.get('place')
            rental.water = request.POST.get('water')
            rental.amenities = request.POST.get('amenities')
            rental.save()
            response['pk-user'] = rental.pk
            return response

        return HttpResponse('Rental Information successfully added')


 class UploadImage(View):
    model = Rental
    template_name = 'rentals/add.html'
    print "Hello"
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return render(request, self.template_name)
    def post(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
        try:
            rental = Rental.objects.get(pk = self.kwargs['pk'])
        except Rental.DoesNotExist:
            error_dict = {'message': 'Rental spae not found'}
        print "Error Rental do not exist"
            return self.render(request,'rentals/add.html',error_dict)
        if request.FILES:
            for file in request.FILES.getlist('image'):
                print('file',file)
                image = Gallery.objects.create(rental = rental, image=file)
                print('image',image)
        print "Uploading Image"
        return HttpResponse("Uploaded successfully")
```

**nginx configuration**

```
upstream app_server {
    server 127.0.0.1:9000 fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    listen 80 default_server;


    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html index.htm;

    client_max_body_size 4G;
    server_name _;

    keepalive_timeout 5;


    gzip                on;
    gzip_http_version   1.0;
    gzip_comp_level     2;
    gzip_proxied        any;
    gzip_min_length     1100;
    gzip_buffers        16 8k;
    gzip_types          text/plain text/html text/css application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    # Some version of IE 6 don't handle compression well on some mime-types, so just disable for them
    gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6].(?!.*SV1)";

    # Set a vary header so downstream proxies don't send cached gzipped content to IE6
    gzip_vary on;



    # Your Django project's media files - amend as required
    location /media  {
        alias /home/django/django_project/media/;
    }

    # your Django project's static files - amend as required
    location /static {
        alias /home/django/django_project/static;
    }

     # Proxy the static assests for the Django Admin panel
    location /static/admin {
       alias /home/django/django_project/static/admin/;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass http://app_server;
    }
}

upstream app_server {
    server 127.0.0.1:9000 fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    listen 80 default_server;


    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html index.htm;

    client_max_body_size 4G;
    server_name _;

    keepalive_timeout 5;


    gzip                on;
    gzip_http_version   1.0;
    gzip_comp_level     2;
    gzip_proxied        any;
    gzip_min_length     1100;
    gzip_buffers        16 8k;
    gzip_types          text/plain text/html text/css application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    # Some version of IE 6 don't handle compression well on some mime-types, so just disable for them
    gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6].(?!.*SV1)";

    # Set a vary header so downstream proxies don't send cached gzipped content to IE6
    gzip_vary on;



    # Your Django project's media files - amend as required
    location /media  {
        alias /home/django/django_project/media/;
    }

    # your Django project's static files - amend as required
    location /static {
        alias /home/django/django_project/static;
    }

     # Proxy the static assests for the Django Admin panel
    location /static/admin {
       alias /home/django/django_project/static/admin/;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass http://app_server;
    }
}
```

Do i need to provide any other information? What might be the cause?

Comment: Yes! please provide the stacktrace as well.

Comment: I dont see any error in your code. Try checking permission for image upload in your digital ocean.

Comment: I gave permission 777 to media directory and now its working. Thanks a lot.

Comment: If i use window.location.href="http://commonrentpspace.me/"; the image wont get upload.